# could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am creating a unit test case for an Akka Actor using `TestActorRef`.

```
def actorRefFactory = context
        implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher
        implicit val OutputActor = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[OutputActor], "OutputActor")

        val actorRef = TestActorRef[OutputActor]
        val actor = actorRef.underlyingActor
```

Getting the following error in creation of actorRef:

```
- could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem
    - not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit t: 
     scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.musigma.muhpc.OutputActor], implicit system: 
     akka.actor.ActorSystem)akka.testkit.TestActorRef[org.musigma.muhpc.OutputActor] in object 
     TestActorRef. Unspecified value parameter system.
```

I am very new to this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All instances of actors, `TestActorRef` or actual real instances, need an `ActorSystem` to reside in.  The methods that instantiate and start actors (again, test or otherwise) require an `implicit` `ActorSystem` to be in scope so that the underlying code creating that actor knows where to put it.

So, taking that into account, you just need to make sure that you add a line of code like this at the start of your test code:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
```

Comment: Yes, this was not specified in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/testing.html. Thanks for pointing it out.